# How to redirect to Phone settings page from my android application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-settings

How to redirect to Phone settings page from my current android application ?
I have already tried with this code. But it is not working.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this one http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
intent.setComponent(cName);
```

and [this](https://github.com/buzeeg/datasettings/blob/master/src/com/remifayolle/android/datasettings/DataSettingsActivity.java)